# Python list iteration with for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to input numbers, and I want my function to return the smallest number.

However, my code seems to stop executing early: as soon as one number in the input is less than the other.

```
a = input("")
smallest = 0
a = a.split(" ")
numbers = a

def smallestindex(numbers):
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        b = int(numbers[i])
        smallest = int(numbers[0])
        print(b)
        if b < smallest:
            smallest = b
            return smallest

print (smallestindex(numbers))
```

Comment: `l = [int(i) for i in numbers]; print(l.index(min(l)))` :-P

Answer (score 4):

This is an indentation issue. Currently your `return` statement happens whenever the `if b < smallest` block gets run. That's probably not what you had intended. You need to unindent that to be at the same level as your `for` statement, so that it runs after the loop ends, not in the middle.

You also need to move the line where you initialize `smallest` to the top of your function, rather than having it happen on each cycle of the loop. Here's how that should look:

```
def smallestindex(numbers):
    smallest = int(numbers[0])    # moved this line up
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        b = int(numbers[i])
        print(b)
        if b < smallest:
            smallest = b
    return smallest   # unindented this line
```

It's also worth noting that you loop could be done slightly differently. Rather than looping over the indexes of the list (using `range(len(numbers))`), you can loop over the list items directly using `for b in numbers`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an indentation error: you're returning `smallest` inside the `for` loop, so executution stops on the first iteration through the loop where the `if` condition is met. You need to return your result after the loop has completed. Also, you're resetting `smallest` each time through the loop, so your `if` block won't do what you intend. Here's a fixed version:

```
def smallestindex(numbers):
    smallest = int(numbers[0])
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        b = int(numbers[i])
        print(b)
        if b < smallest:
            smallest = b
    return smallest
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to return the index of the smallest number as the function's name suggests, you would need to change your code to something like this

```
def smallestindex(numbers):
    numbers = [int(x) for x in numbers] # convert numbers to list of ints
    smallest_idx = 0
    smallest = numbers[0]
    for i, b  in enumerate(numbers):
        if b < smallest:
            smallest_idx = i
            smallest = b
    return smallest_idx
```